# Custom scrollable view in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this scenario where I need to use a flatlist within a scrollview but react native keeps on showing a warning which says, virtualizedLists should never be nested. So I resorted to keep the scrollview as a wrapper and use a view with a scrolling functionality(if possible). Anyone have any idea how to achieve such thing without using any 3rd party packages? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem in some of my apps.

One could restructure the code and add the components above and below the FlatList as header or footer components (`ListHeaderComponent` & `ListFooterComponent`).

Or one could simply tell React Native to ignore the error messages :P

I have not yet found a real problem that has occurred because I ignored the warning. But be aware as it is unsupported the behavior might change in the future.

If you want to ignore `"VirtualizedLists should never be nested"` error messages. You just have to add the code below in your `App.tsx`:

```
import { LogBox } from "react-native";

useEffect(() => {
    LogBox.ignoreLogs(["VirtualizedLists should never be nested"]);
});
```